# How do I create an empty table with SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database

This isn't much of an issue with MySQL per-se.

**The Full Story**

I'm writing a very small PHP framework. It isn't like existing frameworks where they force you to use a certain methodology. It isn't either like a CMS framework. Trust me, I've seen Zend framework and I've used CMSes like Joomla and WordPress extensively, *none of them come close to what I'm doing.*

**Introducing The Issues**

I'm writing the Database abstraction part. You get class methods like ::table_exists() etc.
It is designed in a way that people can easily add different database classes and use them instead (eg; mysql, mssql, oracle, flatfile...).

They simply need to write a class which satisfies a base abstract classes'.

**The Real Issue**

I'm writing the functionality for ::table_create(), but have one main problem: MySQL doesn't like empty tables (ie, without a column).

I have several proposed fixes:

- For each new table, create a commonly used column, such as 'id' (type=INT)
- For each new table, create a temp column which doesn't use any space as much as possible (perhaps a boolean column?)
- Somehow delay table creation until at least one column can be created

This approach is most certainly new, and I'd like to here some unbiased comments about it (anything on the lines of "but no one does it that way" won't do).

Comment: What exactly is the point of this?

Comment: To replace SQL install scripts. These are largely database-dependent, cumbersome to develop and a nightmare to maintain.
By using a modern and flexible framework, one can easily integrate installation scripts with the real code, without extra files and redundant code.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from, started to write a DB schema manipulation library and MySQL is by far the worst one I had to support yet. It has been been written by people who can't recognize some of the most basic stuff the Standard has gotten right. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I would either go with option 1), Adding a generic ID column, which you might find you need anyway, or with option 3) Delaying the table creation. I'm assume after they call ::table_create() they will be calling table_add_col(), etc. So just delay creation until there is at least one column, OR until they actually try and use the table for the first time.

Comment: I'm giving you points since it answers my issue perfectly.

The end developer doesn't even need to know what a table is. Making the system managing tables automatically is well suited for a framework.

Creating the table when a column is added is exactly how this needs to work.

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed fixes look quite good. But I would recommen them in a diffrent order. If you are able to delay the creation, tht's probably the best. My second favorite would be to have a table with only an ID, although you might be delete this column, if you want to create a many-to-many relations table with two foreign keys only.

Comment: Good point! From the current replies, I think I'm siding with the 3rd option.

Answer (score 0):

last of your points.

its really very strange what you are doing here. creating tables on the fly? dynamically or something?
well... whatever you are trying to accomplish. you should have a look at document/object oriented databases like couchdb http://couchdb.apache.org/ ! you can create a document and dynamically add whatever fields you want. those are the closest thing to your "columns"

but as you like it...
your first attempt is ugly because it might lead to conflicts.
the second attempt is clumsy. but if you do so create a col with uniqueprefix_random so you can delete it afterwards.
but its well... i dunno what to say about that.

theird approach seems the only senseful!

Comment: The reason for creating tables dynamically would be, for example, someone writes an extension for the framework and needs a table for himself. Current frameworks (joomla, wordpress etc) require an SQL install script (and a corresponding uninstall script). Sure, I could leave the user this option, but then, what would be the point of creating a framework?

Comment: Arguing with the different approaches: [1] it can't conflict unless people don't know about it (their stuff needs to accomodate with my framework not vice versa). [2] Clumsy is not at all critical, things like "slow" or "over-engineered" are more like it. [3] The problem with this one is that I need to do some form of scheduling, unless in each column_Create() I would make it check for and create a table.